# MYSQL getting total of summed column

Tags: mysql, sql

have this problem for a school example problem where I have to get the total salary for coaches and participants in March (done below) and then I have to sum to get the total salary due in March for all employees which I just want to add onto the end of the Total Salary column.

This is what I have so far:

```
(SELECT Coach.name AS Name, COUNT(*) AS 'Shows Attended In March', 
dailySalary AS 'Daily Salary', sum(dailySalary) AS 'Total Salary' 
FROM Coach, TVShow, CoachInShow 
WHERE monthname(dateOfShow)='March' AND 
Coach.idCoach=CoachInShow.idCoach AND TVShow.idShow = 
CoachInShow.idShow 
GROUP BY Coach.name, Coach.dailySalary)

UNION

(SELECT Participant.name AS Name, COUNT(*) AS 'Shows Attended In 
March', dailySalary AS 'Daily Salary', sum(dailySalary) AS 'Total 
Salary'
FROM Participant, TVShow, Contender, ContenderInShow
WHERE monthname(dateOfShow)='March' AND Participant.idContender = 
Contender.idContender AND Contender.idContender = 
ContenderInShow.idContender AND ContenderInShow.idShow = TVShow.idShow
GROUP BY Participant.name, Participant.dailySalary);
```

I tried using GROUP BY WITH ROLLBACK on the whole thing but it doesn't add up only the TotalSalary columns. I've spent a while on this and kinda stumped.

I pasted the data here for what I'm working with: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gPKVQrZCMkvHUqViAUzCqZ/0 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/535f6d/1

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `SUM(dailySalary)` and also have `dailySalary` in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Arnaiz, do you want a row which shows the sum of salary from "total salary" of the selected records from your query?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `UNION` into a subquery. In the main query, sum all the counts and total salaries, and use `WITH ROLLUP` to get the grand total.

You don't need `dailySalary` in the `GROUP BY` clause, since it's functionally dependent on the ID.

```
SELECT name AS Name, SUM(count) AS `Shows Attended in March`, SUM(totalSalary) AS `Total Salary`
FROM (
    SELECT Coach.name, COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(dailySalary) AS totalSalary
    FROM Coach
    JOIN CoachInShow ON Coach.idCoach=CoachInShow.idCoach
    JOIN TVShow ON TVShow.idShow = CoachInShow.idShow 
    WHERE monthname(dateOfShow)='March'
    GROUP BY Coach.idCoach

    UNION

    SELECT Participant.name, COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(dailySalary) AS totalSalary
    FROM Participant
    JOIN Contender ON Participant.idContender = Contender.idContender 
    JOIN ContenderInShow ON Contender.idContender = ContenderInShow.idContender
    JOIN TVShow ON ContenderInShow.idShow = TVShow.idShow
    WHERE monthname(dateOfShow)='March'
    GROUP BY Participant.idParticipant
) AS x
GROUP BY Name
WITH ROLLUP
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gPKVQrZCMkvHUqViAUzCqZ/5)